# Two-dimensional array (matrix) memory allocation troubles

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I have few lines of C++ code which has simple purpose - to store a matrix in two-dimensional array and not consume more memory, than is needed. This means I have to allocate memory for each number in matrix before putting it in matrix.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int ** matrix;

    matrix = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*));

    // Fill in the matrix
    matrix[0] = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    matrix[0][0] = 5;
    matrix[0][1] = 10;
    matrix[0][2] = 15;

    matrix[1] = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    matrix[1][0] = 2;
    matrix[1][1] = 4;
    matrix[1][2] = 6;

    int i, n;

    // Print the whole matrix
    for (n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            printf("%i\t", matrix[n][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When i compile the code above and runs it, it crashes when printing the matrix:

**3838 Segmentation fault (core dumped) sh "${SHFILE}"**

The stackdump looks like this:

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=0040126A
eax=00000000 ebx=00B0021C ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=6123DBAA edi=61179FC3
ebp=0028CD18 esp=0028CCF0 program=C:\workspace\c\PA1_9\dist\Debug\Cygwin_4.x-Windows\pa1_9.exe, pid 3828, thread main
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0028CD18  0040126A  (6123DBAA, 61179FC3, 0028CD58, 61006CD3)
0028CD58  61006CD3  (00000000, 0028CD94, 61006570, 7EFDE000)
End of stack trace
```

I guess there will be some troubles with pointers/values... but i don't know where and why...

Comment: On a side note, there is memory leak in the program.

Comment: Sure it is! It's just gross bad C++. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're code is almost correct, but the matrix allocation is wrong. You are allocating space to store a single `int *` while you try to initialize two elements (`matrix[0]` and `matrix[1]`) :

```
matrix = (int**)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
```

The outer printing loop is wrong : there are only 2 "lines" in the matrix (with 3 columns each). The program will crash when you attempt to access `matrix[2]` :

```
// Print the whole matrix
for (n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%i\t", matrix[n][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: 2icecream: I'd like to accept the answer, but I can do that in 7 minutes after posting my question... so wait few more minutes please :))

Answer (score 4):

If you know that the matrix is 3x3, why all the `malloc`s? Why not simply:

```
int matrix[3][3];
```

That also takes care of releasing the memory automatically. (You forgot to call `free` in your code!)

Comment: He did not "forget" to call free(). The program terinates at 'return 0;' ... no need to call free.